# Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:App.Views:PostsPage" when adding a PostsPage to Project's AppShell.xaml inside Views folder

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I've added a new page to my .net maui project named PostsPage.xaml - for some reason I'm getting an error when trying to add it to my AppShell.xaml and it's not making sense to me. Probably just something super easy that I'm just overlooking but hoping a fresh set of eyes can spot it for me.

I have the PostsPage.xaml (and accompanying PostsPage.xaml.cs) file in my Views folder along with all my other pages:

[image]

```
<ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:GuidelinesPage}"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'icon_guidelines.svg', iOS='icon_guidelines.svg', MacCatalyst='icon_guidelines.svg'}" />

        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'icon_settings.svg', iOS='icon_settings.svg', MacCatalyst='icon_settings.svg'}" />

        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PostsPage}"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'icon_posts.svg', iOS='icon_posts.svg', MacCatalyst='icon_posts.svg'}" />

        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}"
            Icon="{OnPlatform 'icon_about.png', iOS='icon_about_ios.png', MacCatalyst='icon_about_ios.png'}" />
```

This line is where it is saying this error occurs.  I am at a loss.

```
<ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PostsPage}"
```

I've tried going through every line of code to make sure it matches the way the other pages are implemented, I'm not seeing anything wrong/different.

From PostsPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="App.Views.PostsPage" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:PostsViewModel"
             Title="Post">
```

and from PostsPage.xaml.cs

```
using App.Models;
using App.Services;

namespace App.Views
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Posts), "Posts")]
    public partial class PostsPage : ContentPage
```

Comment: how is `views` defined in your XAML, and what namespace is `PostPage` in?  Note that namespace has nothing to do with folder structure

Comment: I added those to the bottom of this question just now for better clarity, but views is x:Class="App.Views.PostsPage"  and namespace is namespace App.Views

Comment: no, I asked how `views` is defined.  You are using that as a namespace in `AppShell` so it must be defined there

Comment: @Jason 

Oh got ya, it looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell 
x:Class="App.AppShell" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"

    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">`

Thank you

Comment: Also looks like I have this in AppShell.xaml.cs, which is kind of strange since it is the only one in there - nothing for the other pages:

`Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PostsPage), typeof(PostsPage));'

Comment: For future reference, when providing additional code, please edit the question and add it there. This keeps question up-to-date, and is easier to read code in question than in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I see, thank you.  My account is like 7 years old but I just started using the site.  I edited that comment like 10 times trying to figure out how to get the code to format properly, lol.  I'll do this going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the mystery goes unsolved, but after deleting PostsPage.xaml and PostsPage.xaml.cs from the project, then recreating them (cutting and pasting the content out and back in from a text editor with no changes), and the running the project despite the error still showing it errors - it built and removed the error ‍♂️

Comment: FYI: Sometimes Intellisense can't figure out XAML references until a successful build. Its also possible that Rebuild Solution would have fixed it, without deleting and adding back in.

Comment: Interesting.  Well TIL :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - can you add this as an answer so I can mark it?  I think it's the best thing that explains the solution to the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Lets leave it as is, since we don't know for sure whether that would have fixed it for you. Good enough that people can find your answer, and my first comment on it.

Comment: I am facing this exact same error when try to add a new xaml page file to my project. I am also using VS on MAC. The error is not going at all. Any idea what can I do now? Please take have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952630/the-correct-method-for-adding-a-net-maui-content-page-xaml-in-visual-studio-f)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the xnls: local address.

xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:App.Views"