# The Correct Method for Adding a .NET MAUI Content Page (XAML) in Visual Studio for Mac and Dealing with the Error 'Error XFC0000

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, maui

I recently began learning .NET MAUI, so please accept my apologies if the question appears basic. In my project, I have added a .NET MAUI Content page (XAML) called `HomePage` inside a folder, and they have been added to the project (verified by checking the directory of those files). However, when I attempt to use them in the AppShell.xaml file, the file names are not appearing in the suggestion list.

[image]

Interestingly, when attempting to use the default 'MainPage,' it appears in the list.

[image]

However, during the app build process using the newly added file, I always encounter the following error:

```
/Users/rex/Documents/Projects/Project_Name/MainProject/Project_Name/AppShell.xaml(9,9): Error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:XXX:HomePage". (XFC0000) (Project_Name) XamlC
```

I've searched for this error but haven't found a concrete solution or the root cause. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default namespace `local` refer to the root directory of your app by `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourAppName"`,so you cannot refer to the `ContentPage`(`HomePage`) defined in other folders inside of your app directly.

You need to add the namespace for the ContentPage (XAML) (`HomePage`) inside of the folder(suppose the folder is `MyAppName\Pages`).

You can add the following namespace inside of `Shell.xaml`

```
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyAppName.Pages"
```

Then you can refer to the `HomePage`  with `ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyAppName.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppName"
   
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyAppName.Pages"
   
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="MyAppName">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

**Note:**

To make it easier to understand, I shared the screenshot of my test app:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing such an elaborate answer. I was looking for something like this, and it works. I was also wondering about a similar configuration issue where the file was not getting attached properly to the project, hence it wasn't recognizing the newly added file.